# An error occurred attempting to determine the process id of dotnet.exe which is hosting your application.A task was canceled

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-2.1, angular4-router

When I try to startup my project w/ IIS Express I get the error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdhKI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS 2017

- Project Properties
- Debug
- Launch Browser //http://localhost:5000 or whatever
- Uncheck Enable SSL
- App Url //http://localhost:5000 or whatever. make sure same with Launch Browser url
- Save and Close
- Open launchsettings.Json under Properties (Solution Explorer)
- Make sure old settings is deleted. If not delete it.
- Save and Close.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error when trying to launch a downloaded project in which the target framework version was different from the version installed in my environment. I opened the “.csproj” file in a text editor, corrected the version in the “TargetFramework” node and saved the modified file. In order to be sure to make the changes take effect, I closed and reopened the Visual Studio solution containing the project. Then the project started correctly.